# Why my route nesting system doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've spend whole day trying to understand why it doesn't work...

If I go to `localhost:3000/api` I expect to see API, and I see it. Okay.

But, when I go to `localhost:3000/api/auth` I expect to see AUTH, it shows API for some reasons.

What's wrong with my route system?

Folder structure:

```
-- routes
   -- api
      index.js
   index.js
server.js
```

#### server.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const indexRoute = require("./routes/index");

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.use(indexRoute);

app.listen(3000);
```

#### routes/index.js

```js
const router = require("express").Router();

router.use("/api", (req, res) => res.status(200).send("API"));

module.exports = router;
```

#### routes/api/index.js

```js
const router = require("express").Router();

router.use("/auth", (req, res) => res.status(200).send("AUTH"));

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: In `routes/index.js`, you aren't referencing your endpoints from `routes/api/index.js` at all. You are just responding. You have to require the `api` module, then use that in the route. Think of it this way; you need `routes/index.js` to act as middleware, let the specific route files and endpoints do the responding to clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass both routers, import the router in
`routes/api/index.js` and pass it as a second argument.

`app.use(indexRoute, secondRoute);`

This is called modular routing and as the documentation states it:
A Router instance is a complete middleware and routing system; for this reason, it is often referred to as a “mini-app”.

https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html